# How to print all instances of a substring in a string

Tags: java, string, file, substring

So, I currently have a file, and I'm trying to have a command that searches through all of the lines in that text that has what I'm looking for.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class finder
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
       Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

       String search = console.nextLine();
       Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\test.txt"));

       while (s.hasNextLine())
       {
         String temp = s.nextLine();
         if (temp.contains(search))
         {
            System.out.println(temp);
         }
       }
   } //Main

} //Finder
```

The text looks like this

```
Bob has a cat
Bob has a dog
Chris has a cat
```

If I search "cat", it will print out "Bob has a cat", and "Chris has a cat".
If I search "Bob", it will print out "Bob has a cat", and "Bob has a dog".

So I don't know what to put in the while loop. I know you have to do something with the indexOf string command, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Why do you need indexOf? You can do string.contains if you don't care about word boundaries

Comment: Also, are you sure you want an empty line before the scanned file content?

Comment: So just loop over each line and print out lines that contain given word.

Comment: Please at least make an effort to figure it out yourself. Posting all of the non-applicable code and asking us to do the actual work isn't really a good way to learn something. We're glad to help, but you should try to do something at least. An empty `while` loop and *what goes here?* isn't effort.

Comment: What is the desired behavior? I don't get why the output you show us should be wrong, sounds correct to me. Or what are you trying to achieve? Note that reading and writing files is nowadays done with Javas new I/O API called **NIO** revolving around classes `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`.

Comment: Oh sorry I already edited the code @Zabuza

Comment: Thanks for editing, now what output is that producing compared to what you expect?

Comment: If m not wrong, the current code should produce the expected output...

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match the whole line just call `contains` on a given `String` line to filter the ones you desire:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "chris";
        List<String> dataList = Arrays.asList("Bob has a cat", "Bob has a dog", "Chris has a cat");
        dataList.stream().filter(str -> str.toLowerCase().contains(query)).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
Chris has a cat
```

If you want something more elaborate, like getting all the indexes of the matches of your query in a given line, then you should try with `Pattern` and `Matcher` ([pretty good tutorial here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#pattern-and-matcher)):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "bob";
        System.out.println("Searching for \"" + query + "\"...");
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(query);
        Arrays.asList(
                "Bob has a cat bob", 
                "Bob has a dog", 
                "Chris has a cat",
            "Cat has a chris that is a bob")
        .forEach(line -> {
            System.out.println("Checking in line = \"" + line + "\"");
            Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(line.toLowerCase());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("found! index = " + matcher.start());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
Searching for "bob"...
Checking in line = "Bob has a cat bob"
found! index = 0
found! index = 14
Checking in line = "Bob has a dog"
found! index = 0
Checking in line = "Chris has a cat"
Checking in line = "Cat has a chris that is a bob"
found! index = 26
```

Plug in your file reading with `java.nio` and happy coding!

Cheers!